# Why does this line cause a boolean error?

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

```
len([True for i in a if any([any(j == b[:, 0]) for j in i])])
```

This is my line of code. `a` is a multidimensional list and `b` is a nd.array. When I run it, it returns this error:

```
The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Even though I used `any()` at every place that is needed. Where's my mistake?

Edit: Values for the lists:

1. `a = [[[[0, 0], [0, 0]]]]`
2. `b = np.array([[[[0, 0], [0, 0]], 0]])`

Comment: can you add values in 
`allStates` and `self.wins` to you question so we can test it out too

Comment: @Yatin I added some examples to the question.

Comment: How many values can you remove from those lists, and how much can you remove from the failing statement while still reproducing the same error?

Comment: @mercator I can reduce the statement to `len([True for i in a if any([any(j == b[:, 0]) for j in i])])` with `a = [[[[0,0],[0,0]]]]` and `b = np.array([[[[0, 0], [0, 0]], 0]])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is produced by:

```py
any(j == b[:, 0])
```

use:

```py
(j == b[:, 0]).any()
```

instead. Same for the outer `any()`. Note that `any()` can take an iterable, which `np_array.any()` is a function from numpy.